# How to display quickly additional data on a mobile screen having a single row ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, compact-framework, mobile

I have a Windows Mobile application written in .NET
We use a ListView to show a list of bookings. We show the date and the subject of the booking.

That's pretty limited. We would like to show quickly if possible additional data, like who created the booking, the location for the booking. The ListView on Compact Framework doesn't let us to use multi lines for rows.

We provide a details form for the booking, but our customers want to see more while they are in the list of the bookings.

How would you handle this? It should be quick, and fit the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you're using a ListView.  Do you actually want to show individual columns of information, or just several pieces at once?  You may want to look at the OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.ListBox2 class, part of the OpenNETCF Smart Device Framework.  It defaults to showing a single plain text string and wrapping it across multiple lines, but also offers hooks for custom drawing list items.  There's a [sample project](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2007/05/16/sdf-sample-custom-drawing-a-list-and-viewing-all-network-adapters-too/) available which demonstrates custom drawing.

The OpenNETCF SDF is available at [opennetcf.com](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx).  I've used some of their code in a few of my Compact Framework projects, and it's been extremely useful.